# HTML / PHP: Which parts of an HTML head can be saved in a separate file

Tags: php, html, include, html-head

I am new to HTML and hope someone can help me with this.

I am trying to set up a website where the code for every page is saved as a separate php file. 
Since all these pages use the same **document head** and includes **I would like to remove as much as possible of this from the pages and save it in a separate includes file** (`header.php`) which I can then include using PHP.

My current head looks as follows and since this is the same on all pages I currently have ALL this saved in the separate header.php file and then just use `<?php include "header.php"; ?>` on the single pages.

Can someone tell me which parts of this should remain on the single pages for a proper setup and if anything should be changed or added here ?

**Note:** jQuery and JS are included separately in the footer.

**My PHP (header file):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="author" content="John Doe" />
        <meta name="description" content="Created: 2015-06" />

        <base href="http://www.MyURL.com" target="_self" />

        <!-- CSS -->        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/styles.css" />
        <!-- CSS - Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: You're doing it right. If the header and footer are duplicated on every pages then it makes sense to put those in separate files then include them in. The advantage is that if you need to make a change to one of these sections then you edit it in one place. Unique functionality will generally be in it's own file. For example a Contact Form would be on the contact page and not in the header where it will be included in every public facing page.

Comment: @Maxxi: Thanks - I was just wondering if any of the HTML tags should remain on the page as otherwise the page itself looks like it is missing opening or closing tags (e.g. when I also save <body> in the separate file. I know PHP adds this so this is just about doing it the right way.

Comment: Why not try some template engines? I.e. Smarty?

Comment: @Philipp: Thanks for this - Since I just started with programming I feel like I learn it better if I do things myself instead of using templates or generators.

Comment: I write my web apps the same way you have shown - opening body and content div in the header, then I close them in the tail. Then the 'body' of each page does not have to worry about these, and can just contain what is important. Seems to work fine for me, but I'm interested to see if anyone suggests another method.

Comment: @keewee279 — Don't confuse a particular **PHP file** with the **HTML document** that is sent to the browser (or the **page** which consists of that file and anything it depends on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Top head file (top_head.php):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <?php if(isset($page_author)){ ?>
            <meta name="author" content="<?php echo $page_author; ?>" />
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if(isset($page_description)){ ?>
            <meta name="description" content="Created: 2015-06" />
        <?php } ?>

        <!-- CSS -->        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/styles.css" />
        <!-- CSS - Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

        <title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
```

**Your current header file:**

```
<?php
      $page_title = 'Hello';
      $page_description = 'This is a beautiful description';
?>
<?php include("top_head.php"); ?>
</head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: Just one question to add here: Is there a specific reason why the "</head>" is not also saved in the separate header file ?

Comment: I think it's so you can add to the `head` section in specific files, else you've already closed it. But you could achieve this just as easily by including more variables in the `head` section.

Comment: Update: Just to add (after applying all the suggestions from here) I switched to require_once() instead of using include() to include the separate files here.

Comment: That's only really necessary if there is any chance you could try to include the file more than once, I would suggest `require_once()` is overkill in this situation and an include is fine, but it doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the general idea...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="author" content="John Doe" />
    <meta name="description" content="Created: 2015-06" />
    <base href="http://www.MyURL.com" target="_self" />

    <!--
    Your paths need to relative to the websites root directory or the full
    URL else they may not work depending on where the file is located.
    -->     
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/includes/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <!-- 
    This line just echos the title if one has been set or a default string
    if the title hasn't been set. You will need to ensure every page that
    includes this file sets the title before including this file. You may
    also want to take this approach with other values.
    -->
    <title><?php echo isset($title) ? $title : 'Default Title'; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This looks good. So regarding my question should I put all of this in the separate header file ?

Comment: Yes, call it header.php and include it in the files where it is needed. Make sure you close the 'wrapper' `div` somewhere, in a footer include would be a good idea : )

Comment: No problem, the way I have coded the title (using the ternary operator) is the best way to do it I've found as if you forget to set it you still have a default title set. The answer you've marked as correct has some useful content also : )

Answer (score 1):

Since you are starting your  tag in header.php, you can close the  tag on the own page itself (i mean the other pages ie: Contact, About Us, Product, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

The code section you have mentioned in the question can be called as `header.php` and further can be included on each and every page where it is required.

**Apart from this**

1. Header - header.php
2. Main content - main-content.php - this will be specific to each and every page from your website
3. Footer - footer.php - this can also be made common - and further included in every page.
4. Apart from this you can also have a few more php files which might have navigation or any kind of common content blocks.

Example page could be:

```
<?php
include 'header.php'
/*either add here the content or include further php files*/
include 'about-us.php'
include 'footer.php'
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! - So in this case would I put all the above in my header or should I leave any of the HTML on the single pages ?

Comment: Exactly @keewee279. Please make sure that code doesn't get repeated in any of the common php files. You will need to use lot of thought process for **point # 2**.

Comment: Thanks again ! I hope I have the page content sorted out already, at least for the first few pages.

Comment: @keewee279 - thats good. If you have flexibility in selection of the tool for making the websites then I suggest you please try with CMSs - I would like to suggest DRUPAL - www.drupal.org.

Comment: Thanks for that ! I have styled my own navbar, buttons and form fields etc. so this should be sorted already and it helped me to get used to CSS. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right, the parts that are shared between all the pages should be placed in a separate php file, this greatly improve your life when you have to maintain the site (immagine add a stylesheet or a library to every page of your site after some time ...).

To help SEO you should specify a title and maybe some meta tag that are page specific.

Also consider carefully if you have other parts that are repeated in every page for example a left or right bar or a particular widget (for example a banner image or something like that)

Comment: Thanks for this - yes, I will create similar files for the footer and navbar etc. :)